# Rendering a Tree Using render collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, recursion, partial

I have a site with reviews. When displaying them, the first review for an item should not be  indented, but subsequent ones should be.

The HTML output should look something like:

```
<ul>
  <li>review for item 1</li>
  <li>
    review for item 2
    <ul>
      <li>2nd review  for item 2</li>
      <li>3rd review for item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The output I'm getting looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>review for item 1</li>
  <li>
    review for item 2
  </li> <!-- wrong -->
  <li>  <!-- wrong -->
    <ul>
      <li>2nd review  for item 2</li>
      <li>3rd review for item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

_reviews.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "review_item", :collection => @reviews, :locals => { :reviews_local => @reviews } %>
```

_review_item.html.erb

```
<% if review_item_counter == 0 %>
<ul>
<% end %>

    <li>
    <% if @current_reviewable != review_item.id %>
       <% @current_reviewable = review_item.id %>
           <%= review_item.body %>

    <% else %>

        <% reviews_local.slice!(review_item_counter, reviews_local.size) %>
        <%= render :partial => "review_item", :collection => reviews_local, :locals => { :reviews_local => reviews_local } %>

    <% end %>
    </li>

<% if review_item_counter == reviews_local.size - 1 %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was able to do this with iteration and divs much more easily. The recursion is really creating a headache.